# Collection View Items being reused error (Swift)

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have a UICollectionView and the items contain a button. When that button is pressed it runs this piece of code `sender.hidden = true`. However, as the items are being reused it hides the button on the item later down on the list. How can I fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Reset the state of your cell in `prepareForReuse` method

Answer (score 0):

in the Cell class override `prepareForReuse()`  and set

```
self.hidden = false
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a `prepareForReuse()`. I am using a UICollectionView. Will it be different?

Comment: UICollectionView is a container of UICollectionViewCell

Comment: Where should I include this code? In the Cell's file?

Comment: if you create custom cell, yes in the cell file but if not, you can set visibility of cell in `cellForItemAtIndexPath()`

Comment: That works when scrolling down the list but it does not continue when I go back to the selected item (understandably). How would you recommend I do that. Should I add the selected items to an array then check against it?

Comment: you have to store only a selected `indexPath` or just selected `row` if you have one section

Answer (score 0):

Do not (ab)use the UI elements as data source. You should store the state of the buttons
in a model object (e.g. an array). Then you can set the correct state in
the `collectionView(_:cellForItemAtIndexPath:)` method (which is called each time
before a cell is displayed).